# An exercise of positive element in C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital C*-algebra and $\{b_{n}\}$ be a positive invertible sequence in $A$. If $||1_{A}-b_{n}||\rightarrow 0$, **can we conclude $||1_{A}-b_{n}^{-\frac{1}{2}}||\rightarrow 0$ ?**

Answer (score 4):

Since $b_n\geq0$ and $b_n\to1$, eventually we will have $\sigma(b_n)\subset (k_1,k_2)$ for $k_1,k_2> 0$ and sufficiently close to $1$. Then
$$
\|1_A-b_n^{-1/2}\|=\|b_n^{-1}(1_A-b_n)(1_A+b_n^{-1/2})^{-1}\|\\
\leq\|b_n^{-1}\|\,\|1_A-b_n\|\,\|(1_A+b_n^{-1/2})^{-1}\|
\leq k_1^{-1}\,(1+k_2^{-1/2})^{-1}\,\|1_A-b_n\|$$

Comment: Change $1A$ to $1_A$.

Comment: @Martin Argerami 1.How to conclude that $\sigma(b_{n})\subset(k_{1}, k_{2})$? 2. why is $(1_{A}+b_{n}^{-1/2})$ invertible? 3. How can you get $||b_n^{-1}||||(1_A+b_n^{-1/2})^{-1}||
\leq k_1^{-1}(1+k_2^{-1/2})^{-1}$?

Comment: 1. If $\|1_A-b\|<d$, then $\sigma(b)\subset(1-d,1+d) $

Comment: 2. If $b\geq0$, then $1_A+b$ is invertible as its spectrum is inside $[1,\infty) $.

Comment: 3. The inequality is a direct consequence of $k_1\,1_A\leq b_n\leq k_2\,1_A$, so $\|b_n\|\leq k_2$, $\|b_n^{-1}\|\leq k_1^{-1} $, etc.